# Flutter Inner Text Shadow (Inset)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to recreate an inner text shadow effect on some text.

The closest i've found is this https://github.com/johynpapin/flutter_inset_box_shadow but it seems to be for box shadows only.

How would I achieve something similar for text widgets instead?
[image]